# Enable image caching at Node.js OpenShift server

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, openshift

I have a static website deployed at OpenShift using Node.js server. Every time I update the page it loads everything, everything including images gets downloaded again. How can I make the browser cache images? I've tried setting `res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=1209600');` in the request handler but it has no effect. When I examine the request with devtools it says that there really is such response header but the request has header `max-age=0`. Is this a problem? Anyway, images are still downloading every time I update the page. How can I enable caching for them?

Comment: Show please screenshot of response headers, or share the link to example.

Comment: @VitalyKulikov http://s14.postimg.org/93mk5udy9/headers.png  and a link:  http://wiseman-gnwp.rhcloud.com/  thank you for your effort

Comment: As far as I can see, everything is cached properly https://s.mail.ru/5APUepxrD6a3/img-2016-03-21-17-42-45.png

Comment: @VitalyKulikov Is this screenshot taken after you've refreshed the page or typed  the address or navigated somewhere else from the page and then clicked "back"?

Comment: Problem is with the way you refresh page in a browser. You probably click on reload button, but try to press enter while address bar is focused, you'll see that resources are loaded from cache. It's a browser feature, they reload resources if you click reload :-)

Comment: @VitalyKulikov OMG, really. pretty strange browser feature I'd say.. Thank you!